# List comprehension on list of tuples, haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

My function vector1 takes a tuple of the type (Double,Double,Double) and it should multiply all items in the tuple by -1 and return a list with a tuple of negative doubles. The code compiles, but infinitely loops.

```
vector1 (p,q,r)= let
  y=(p,q,r)
  y'=[(-1)*y | (y)<-y']
  in y'
```

Comment: A list with a tuple? Can you show an example of the output you’d like?

Comment: input (1,2,3)->output[(-1,-2,-3)]

Comment: so `vector1 (p, q, r) = [(-p, -q, -r)]`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant

Comment: @bubu Hi! don't forget to mark one question (only one) as accepted if you found it useful! You have never done before

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you were trying to do a list comprehension on `y`, not `y'`:

```
vector1 (p,q,r)= let
  y=(p,q,r)
  y'=[(-1)*x | x<-y]
  in y'
```

but that won’t work either, because list comprehensions are for lists. Tuples of different sizes are different types entirely. Since you’re already unpacking `(p, q, r)`, you can apply `-` to each of them manually (and then wrap it in a list for whichever reason):

```
vector1 (p, q, r) = [(-p, -q, -r)]
```

If you feel like defining a `map` for triples:

```
map3 :: (a -> b) -> (a, a, a) -> (b, b, b)
map3 f (p, q, r) = (f p, f q, f r)

vector1 :: Num a => (a, a, a) -> [(a, a, a)]
vector1 = pure . map3 negate
```